# help with jquery onchange event on dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, select, drop-down-menu

I would like to be able to launch an alert message everytime the value of the dropdown is changed. I thought the code below should have worked but it is not for some unknow reason. Any ideas why?

Thanks.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("select").change(function(){
        alert(this.id);
    });
</script>


<select>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The code is fine, you just aren't initialising it correctly.

Try....

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select").change(function(){
        alert(this.id);
    });
});
```

see the documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Your function alerts the `id` of the `select` element (which you haven't assigned to anything anyway). I'm assuming you actually wanted to get the value from the dropdown? In which case you want:

```
alert($(this).val());
```

Answer (score 3):

Register the onchange handler once the DOM is ready on page load.

```
$(function() {

   $("select").change(function(event) {
        alert(this.id);
        // alert( $(this).attr('id') ); to get the id attr with jquery
    });

});
```

I would also suggest targeting the select element with an id. Your code will show an alert every time *any* select on the page is changed.

Comment: @Slaks: Ha, no problem. Not fussed who, just a bit baffled about why

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#projectsName").change(function(){
       alert("HI");
});
```

});

Please Note that projectName is the id of dropdown 
and there is no other id with the same name
other wise jquery will not work
also double check your jquery plugin